# Does anybody manufacture extra-wide (3E/4E or EEE/EEEE ) wide road or mountain biking shoes?

Tags: shoes, clipless, spd

I have mutant-wide feet and it's generally impossible to find comfortable shoes for any occasion. For the most part my only options in life are New Balance. I'm cycling a lot lately and would like to take advantage of cleats. So, does anybody actually manufacture 4E shoes? I'd rather not try stretching them out with mink oil/boiling water/wooden shoe stretchers and the pain from narrow shoes can be pretty excruciating. My google-fu is coming up with a few dozen forum discussions with no real solutions.

Comment: I also mostly wear NB 4E. Didn't try that hard, but pretty much gave up on finding cycling shoes. I seem to recall hearing that some people have had good luck with cycling sandals, since sandals tend to be a bit more forgiving on sizing.

Answer (score 10):

Sidi make a wide fitting version of their shoes.

I have a pair of Sidi's and they have been the best fitting, most comfortable shoes I've ever found. From [their website](http://www.sidiamerica.com/sidi/sidi_fit.html):

> Mega sizes are cut with more material throughout, and a larger-volume heelcup. Mega sizes roughly correspond to a EE/EEE width on the Brannock sizing scale.

Possibly still not wide enough for your needs but they're worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Sidi. I just bought new shoes recently and totally discounted Sidi, never even looking them because of past experiences with them being narrower then other brands. I will have to try on some of these.

Comment: I'm going down to Sports Basement to try out the Shimano M087GEs and Northwave Lizzard Pros today. I tried to buy a pair of Sidi Megas but apparently the customers of the high-end bike stores never have feet longer than 42s, which made me feel like even more of a mutant.

Comment: @mhalligan I had to order my Sidi's as I couldn't find any shops that stocked them. I got them from a specialised cycling shop, not just a standard LBS.

Comment: I picked up the Shimano M087GEs from [Sports Basement](http://sportsbasement.com) in San Francisco tonight, they feel flimsier than the Sidis but wider and more comfortable.  I'll have a better idea as to their fit after a few days of wear.

Answer (score 4):

I have 4E feet and the only shoes that I have found that fit are Lake

Comment: user8186, May you please help here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893399/understanding-meromorphic-holomorphic-forms-on-riemann-surface (i also commented in one of your bicycle se posts)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [D2 Shoes](http://www.d2shoe.com) will make you a custom extra-wide shoe.

Good info on the D2 Shoes website. 41 sizes, 9 widths available. $975 price tag is tough, but looks like D2 Shoes will manufacture you an extra wide road or mountain shoe.

The widest off the shelf bicycle shoe I could find is the Shimano SH-M087GE Mountain Bike Shoes. The GE version is a wide version of the regular SH-M087G.

Comment: On that note, the [Lake MX400s](http://www.bicycleapparel.com/shoelakecustom.html) might also be an option, at 1/2 the price of the D2's .. $975 for a pair of shoes is pretty obscene. But man those Lakes are fugly!

Comment: I have not tried heat molded shoes (Shimano makes a shoe you heat up too) but even the $480 on those Lakes is too much in my opinion. I don't know how much the material will stretch with the heat molding.

Answer (score 1):

Once met a guy who had had his shattered foot "reconstructed" with screws, etc, and it was about half-again as wide as his other foot.  He was riding in custom-reconstructed cycling shoes.  He told me that the cobbler took two regular bike shoes, cut them apart, and sewed them back together as one.

As I recall (it's been maybe eight years), the shoes had cleats, probably SPDs.

(Of course, I have no idea who did the work for him, but probably an outfit that does "orthopedic" shoes.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a cheap pair of shoes from Specialized that are awesome for wide feet. The [Tahoe From Specialized](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/ftr/shoes/recreationalfitnessshoes/tahoe).  Note: this isn't a 'competitive' shoe; it's classified as recreational. I ride a hybrid for fitness, and I wear 10.5 US 4E New Balances when I buy athletic shoes.  I paid $85 from a retailer but I think you can get them cheaper.

The shoe works because of the construction. They're built like Keen or Merrell sandals, meaning they wrap around your foot in a basket-like construction. It's not a sandal though, in that the sides of the shoe have strips of leather and nylon that flex around the toe box.(don't know if I'm using the right terms) Again, I'm a fitness rider, and I need a versatile shoe for commutes and long rides. And I've been wearing them on long rides for two weeks without any pain. These have a pop-out section on the forefoot to accomodate a clip if you want to install one.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out custom=made shoes from [BONT](http://www.bont.com/cycling/). They aren't cheap though!

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible, if you have the tools and the inclination, to make your own from a pair of non-cycling shoes that already fit correctly. Ideally these should have a flattish outsole (so they don't catch on the pedals) which is also thick enough to recess the cleats.

You'll still ideally want the stiff insole from a cycling shoe (as [here](http://djcatnap.com/?p=680)) to spread the pressure from the plate the cleats bolt onto.  So, you need a donor cycling shoe whose sole isn't *too* narrow, but at least it doesn't need to fit around your feet for this to work.